# Модуль python не устанавливается полностью

Tags: python

Устанавливаю модуль (библиотеку?) reportlab по этой ссылке

https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/downloads/

После чего через консоль хочу установить его:
python setup.py install

И никаких ошибок, казалось бы, не выводит. Но когда в программе хочу задействовать этот модуль

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
```

Получаю

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test2.py", line 3, in <module> 

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab'
```

И действительно, если я смотрю что установлено, то этой библиотеки нет в списке установленных

То есть я вроде все правильно установил, но на деле ничего не установлено. Я не понимаю в чем дело. Могу предоставить доп данные, чтобы разобраться с этим

Comment: Может кто-нибудь попробовать установить его себе, импортнуть и посмотреть будет ли все норм?

Answer (score 2):

Файл README.txt гласит :

## 2. Installation

In most cases, `easy_install reportlab` or `pip install reportlab` will
do the job.  Full details follow below for each platform.

Через pip install reportlab ставиться без проблем.

Comment: Понял. К сожалению, из-за ограничений на работе, связанных с прокси, я не могу воспользоваться этим методом. А вот если делать как я, то будто не полностью все становится. Спасибо

Comment: @shadow1337 там есть required библиотеки. Придется все их скачать и поставить в систему. У них кстати тоже в свою очередь могут быть зависимости.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич А где я могу найти эти библиотеки?

Comment: @shadow1337 по названию ищете их страницы. Всё что есть в pip и easy_install имеет свои страницы с описанием где взять исходники.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич прошу прощения, но я не могу найти их страницы по названию. Не могли бы вы помочь мне с этим? pdfgen

Comment: @shadow1337 например pypi.org Страница библиотеки из Вашего вопроса https://pypi.org/project/reportlab/

Comment: Так нет, я эту уже качал и устанавливал. В итоге pdfgen не работает

Comment: @shadow1337 pdfgen - это не зависимость, а часть библиотеки reportlab.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич и тогда при установке reportlab строкой в консоли "python install reportlan" все должно установиться, pdfgen должен корректно работать, разве нет? У меня вот даже reportlab не устанавливается таким образом

Comment: @shadow1337 Вам нужно найти все зависимости и установить их до до начала установки reportlab. Их там наверняка очень много. И что самое сложное - у зависимостей тоже могут быть зависимости. Придётся их всех выкачать, и установить. По другому никак в Вашем случае.